# I have a wordpress website "www.thegameofmusic.net". it is not completed yet

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website "www.thegameofmusic.net". it is not completed yet. the home page is working fine but when I click on any menu item, it takes "#wpdance-" by default and redirect to home page automatically. because of this the menu page is not able to be opened. Please help!!

Comment: Source code? Backend? Framework (if used) ? How can we help if you don't provide all those things? You may first want to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have to change the link of the menu in appearence -> navigations (or menu ?, sorry i'v the admin in french)

Comment: from appearence ->menu, there can be picked and dropped the pages directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the "Menu" in appearance section and choose the Menu you want to change and find Home tab and then delete incorrect link